# Data Structures useful in multi-threaded programming

Tags: multithreading, data-structures, concurrency, computer-science

Besides the well known data Structure which can be used in Multi-Threaded programs such as Concurrent Stack, Concurrent Queue, Concurrent List, Concurrent Hashing.
Are there any other lesser know but useful Data Structures which can be used in parallel/Multi-Threaded programming.

Even if they are some different versions of above listed data structures with some optimization, then kindly do share.

Please do include some references.

Edit: Will keep listing what I find

1) ConcurrentCuckooHashing (Optimized version of ConcurrentHashing)

2) ConcurrentSkipList

Comment: Currently the question is too broad. For example, `AtomicInteger` storing a single integer value technically a data structure too. Maybe you can describe what problem do you have?

Comment: @AlexeyMalev : Thanks for your reply. I am practicing multi-threading programming, hence reading more about data structure which I can use, read about the above said data structure, but more or less I already know about them and in general wanted to know and read about other data structures..

Comment: Little complex though, not as simple as AtomicInteger  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will try to answer with examples from JDK, if you do not mind:

**Lists:**

- `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is a list that achieves thread-safe usage by recreating backing array each time the list is modified;
- Lists returned by `Collections.synchronizedList()` are thread-safe as they include exclusive locking for most operations (iteration over is an exception);
- `ArrayBlockingQueue`. Queue that has a fixed size and blocks when there's nothing to pull out or no space to push in;
- `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is a lock-free queue based on Michael-Scott algorithm;
- [Concurrent stack, based on Treiber algorithm](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp04186/). Surprisingly, I didn't find that in JDK;

**Sets:**

- Sets, returned by factory `Collections.newSetFromMap()` with a backing `ConcurrentHashMap`. With these sets you can be sure that its iterators is not prone to `ConcurrentModificationException`, and they use a striping technique for locking it - locking all set is not neccesary to perform some operations. For example, when you want to add element, only the part of the set determined by element `hashCode()` will be locked;
- `ConcurrentSkipListSet`. The thread-safe set based on a [Skip List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) data structure;
- Sets, returned by `Collections.synchronizedSet()`. All points written about similar lists are applicable here.

**Maps:**

- `ConcurrentHashMap` which I already mentioned and explained. Striping is based on item keys;
- `ConcurrentSkipListMap`. Thread-safe map, based on skip list;
- Maps, returned by `Collections.synchronizedMap()`. All points written about similar lists and maps are applicable here.

These were more or less standard data structures intended for multithreaded usage, which should be enough for most practical tasks. I also found some links you may find useful:

- [Wait-free red-black tree](http://www.utdallas.edu/~aravindn/waitfree-rbt.pdf);
- [A huge article about concurrent data structures in general](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~shanir/concurrent-data-structures.pdf);
- [Concurrent structures and synchronization primitives used in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460718%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);
- [Articles about transactional memory](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/stm/) - not really a data structure, but since your request serves academic purposes, worth reading;
- [One more article about transactional memory](http://habrahabr.ru/post/221667/) - Easy to read, but it is in Russian language. If you can read it, definetely worth reading;

Comment: Thank you so much, I have used few of these data structure but few I didn't know, need to practice them :)

Comment: @Kabir Actually I wrote not too much of structures. But anyway, glad to help as always.

Comment: Of course Alexey, which is why I had not marked your answer as accepted :)  , but thank you for sharing your view.

Comment: @Kabir Is there any way to improve my answer so you can accept it? Maybe if you write some details on what do you want to know, I'll be able to help you.

Comment: Recently I read a book on concurrent data structures "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming" which had the above list Concurrent data structures(in my question) besides these I wanted to learn and read about more such concurrent data structures, hence trying to find few..hope it helps..

Comment: @Kabir The formulation "I want to learn and read more" is quite vague. There is always to read more, no way to meet that criteria.

Comment: I would be happy if someone can list or give reference for one or two..not asking for more :)

Comment: @Kabir I added some links which contains mostly general information on the subject.